# Двухсвязный список на Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как правильно начать разрабатывать код для двухсвязного списка и с чего для начала нужно начать.

Список должен поддерживать следующие методы:

- Add,
- InsertBefore(value, …)
- InsertAfter(value, …)
- Delete(…)

Покажите простой пример двухсвязного списка или укажите ссылку с примером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Прочитайте, как устроен двусвязный список.
2. Посмотрите, как реализован java.util.LinkedList.
3. ???
4. PROFIT